I want to make a splash screen in Flutter, but I get this error
I want to add a splash screen. I entered the documentation for Filters and followed the steps, but this problem appeared to me. What is the solution?
Because every version of flutter_test from SDK depends on path 1.8.3 and flutter_native_splash >=2.3.12 depends on path ^1.9.0, flutter_test from SDK is incompatible with flutter_native_splash >=2.3.12.
So, because telecom depends on both flutter_native_splash ^2.4.0 and flutter_test from SDK, version solving failed.

remove version number from the flutter_native_splash.
i.e: flutter_native_splash:

Remove the version specified in flutter_native_splash package or run the command "flutter clean" and then "flutter pub upgrade" to upgrade all the packages.

try
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
